# html5 - seamless audio connection between pages

Tags: javascript, html, audio, local-storage

Alright,

I've got localStorage doing its thing to keep the audio tag on track between two pages:

http://tablapusher.com/location.php

(click on the black box to see this in action)

... so, how to keep that sudden skip from happening? can this be done? i see beatport's player (html5) successfully making these transitions. i don't want to use iframes, as i am working my way away from that. i would imagine it would have something to do with setting up a buffer of audio for before and after the switch, and matching that up with the playing audio via javascript, no? any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for the time being ajax reloads on an element and pushState will do the trick for me. If anyone has a solution for the approach originally mentioned, that would be nifty as well!